# Which IDE is best for extension development?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon, opera-extension

I code for Firefox, Chrome and Opera extensions with Sublime Text and Notepad++.

But I wonder is there any IDE more suitable for extension development?

I tried to code with XCODE but it was no different than Notepad++.

Comment: Use any IDE you like and the built-in Chrome devtools debugger(!!!). Anyway, the question is [off-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Just google for "ide with chrome debugger".

Comment: IDE usually implies things like debuggers, automatic building, deploying, running tests etc. For extensions you would need something that integrates with a browser. Does xcode do any of that? If not then it would barely qualify as IDE in the context of extension development.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1. If you want to build up a **chrome** app/ext you can use the typical client-side web development stack--HTML, CSS, and JavaScript. This means you can use any IDE you would use for building a web front end like WebStorm, Eclipse, Sublime Text, etc.You can also build Chrome apps with Google Dart , Besides Chrome Dev Editor is pretty decent .
2. For **Firefox** you can use Selenium , Selenium IDE is an integrated development environment for Selenium scripts. It is implemented as a Firefox extension, and allows you to record, edit, and debug tests. Selenium IDE includes the entire Selenium Core, allowing you to easily and quickly record and play back tests in the actual environment that they will run in.

Or You can use **Eclipse PDE** .

Comment: Note: CDE is deprecated.